# Jackson transforming XML/Bean into Json Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, jaxb, jackson2

(Please note that i am providing only snippets of codes to explain my situation and these are not full objects)
I am using Jackson2.8.2. I have an xml in below format:

```
<descriptions>
    <description description1="1" description1Text="text1" />
    <description description1="6" description1Text="text2" description2="19" description2Text="Board Member (BRD)" />
</descriptions>
```

I used JAXB to transform this XML into Java POJO as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Phone", propOrder = {
      "descriptions"
}
@XmlRootElement(name="phone")
 public class Phone extends PhoneBase {

 protected Descriptions descriptions;

 getter()
 setter();
 }
```

Descriptions CLass is as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Descriptions", propOrder = {
"description"
})
public class Descriptions {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<Description> description;


 public List<Description> getDescription() {
    if (description == null) {
        description = new ArrayList<Description>();
    }
    return this.description;
}
}
```

When i use Jackson to transform above POJO into JSON, i get below:

```
    {
"descriptions": {
"description": [{
        "description1": "1",
        "description1_text": "text1"
    }, {
        "description1": "6",
        "description1_text": "text2",
        "description2": "19",
        "description2_text": "Board Member (BRD)"
    }
] }  }
```

While i want it to be as follows:

```
{   
"descriptions": [{
        "description1": "1",
        "description1_text": "text1"
    }, {
        "description1": "6",
        "description1_text": "text2",
        "description2": "19",
        "description2_text": "Board Member (BRD)"
    }
]}
```

Please note how i dont want the parent node but children represented as JSON array and the name of this key that of parent.
Can someone please suggest how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try `private List<Description> description;` field with `@XmlElementWrapper`, directly in the `Phone` class.

Comment: Thanks lexicore, this helped me fix this issue

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. It's a good thing to do and you'll get some rep points as a bonus. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question using the pointer from lexicore and changed my phone clas as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Phone", propOrder = {
"description"
 }
@XmlRootElement(name="phone")
public class Phone
          extends PhoneBase
{

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "descriptions")
@JsonProperty(value = "descriptions")
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<Description> description;

public List<Description> getDescription() {
if (description == null) {
    description = new ArrayList<Description>();
}
return this.description;
}
}
```